# Validacion laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Me podrian por favor ayudar en una validacion de laravel.

Como puedo hacer para validar en laravel que para un idRiesgo solo
se pueda ingresa un idControl
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A lo que me refiero es a que por ejemplo solo se pueda un idControl para el idRiesgo obviamente el idRiesgo puede tener otros idControl asociados,
lo estuve intentando con Request, pero veo que solo se pueden validar las propiedades de los campos por ejemplo que sean unique etc...

edito,para mejor entendimiento.

yo tengo esta vista
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

la cual se guarda en esa tabla que te estoy mostrando y el select que aparece que dice control es el idControl que se guarda en la tabla y el idRiesgo llega por parametro de una vista anterior, lo que pasa es lo siguiente.

el idRiesgo puede llegar cuantas veces sea,lo que yo digo es que el idControl por ejemplo el que aparece en la imagen, si ya se ingreso para el idRiesgo al que le estoy ingresando el control no se deberia de dejar ingresar.

Comment: Cuando hablas de idControl e idRiesgo, ¿te refieres a las dos columnas de la tabla que nos muestras?

Comment: Hola si a eso me refiero.

Comment: Si entiendo bien, la idea es que no se repitan los valores que ingreso en el campo idRiesgo no se puedan repetir, ¿es correcto? ¿y que además dichos valores pertenezcan a la columna idControl? Esa parte no la entiendo bien, tal vez nos puedas ilustrar con un mejor ejemplo.

Comment: Mira te ilustro mejor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes utilizar la regla `unique` especificando en la función anónima el valor del campo idRiesgo:

```
$value = Request::get('idRiesgo');
```

Y en el array del Form Request:

```
'idControl' => Rule::unique('tableName')->where(function ($query) use ($value) {
    return $query->where('idControl', $value);
})
```

Más información en: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#rule-unique

Comment: Gracias caballero, me funciono a la perfeccion.